# 18.04 slowdown. Swappiness already set to 1

Tags: 18.04, ram, swap

So I’ve been using Ubuntu 16.04 in an ESXI virtual environment for a while and things were ok.

Recently though I decided I’d upgrade to 18.04 to keep up with the times and save myself needing to do it next year anyway when EoL comes along for 16.04.

Everything went fine with the update except I now keep getting significantly noticeable usage lag (the network is fine) whenever I leave Ubuntu 18.04 turned on for a while and come back to it.

At first it’s just a complete slowdown and just trying to get a terminal to log me in as root takes 20 seconds.

Once I’ve done something though things become a little bit snapper after about 30 seconds but there is still significantly noticeable lag.

I’ve tried to figure out what the problem is and after Googling about it have come to conclusion it’s to do with swap.

When I use my old 16.04 installation it has a swap usage of about 2-4% at most after 2-3 days where as 18.04 has something more like 30-40% after as little as 8 hours being left unattended.

I should point out that I also had a slow down problem with 16.04 but setting its swappiness value to 10 solved it. No such luck with 18.04 though.

I have since tried to lower the swappiness values for 18.04, at first to 10 then to 0 but after reading up about using 0 for 18.04 I got the impression 18.04 doesn’t do 0 the way I thought it would and that 1 is better?

Setting it to 1 has improved things a little. I now only use up to 10-15% swap and I’d say things have become a little bit more snappier and responsive then before.

However things are nowhere close to what they were on 16.04 leaving me with 3 options. The first is to just go back to 16.04 for the time being and hope something changes before next year. The second is to disable swap altogether, which I should note does fix the problem, but I don’t really want to do this as I feel swap is a valuable ability to have running. The third is try 20.04 but I’m not sure if that will be any better than 18.04.

Figuring I needed a 4th option I’ve come here to ask if there is anything else I could try to do to stop the remaining slowdown as well as to ask if 20.04 wouldn’t suffer the same problem or if it might be better?

I’m using a ProLiant DL120 G7 with ESXI 6.7 installed on mechanical hdd’s. Both 16.04 and 18.04 VM’s have the same resources issued to them (10GB RAM) and typically never use more than 4GB of RAM even when left alone for a day or 2. The most I’ve ever seen either of them use was just shy of 5.5GB

Upgrading the hardware is not an option.